# How can I completely remove PGAdmin from my Mac?

Tags: port, postgresql, pgadmin

Problem: I've inadvertently installed both PGAdmin and PostgreSQL on my mac. Unfortunately, PGAdmin is now defaulting to port 5432 and I'm unable to start a database on that port from PostgreSQL.

I've already tried deleting PGAdmin as well as stopping the server from within the UI but according to my Network Utility tool, port 5432 is still listening on that port even when PGAdmin is not running. I've also tried terminal commands to kill the port, but it reestablishes a connection.

Is there any way I can fully remove PGAdmin as well as free up port 5432 to use for PostgreSQL? I've searched for the default system settings where PGAdmin saves port 5432 as the default but I'm unable to locate.